# The presented password is invalid LDAP Symfony 6.*

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony6

i want to Authenticat against an LDAP server , i managed to connect with the ldap server and also i managed to bind with the ldap user provider but i face a problem when i want to login

SERVICE.YAML

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    tags:
        - ldap
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: ldap.forumsys.com
            port: 389
            #encryption: tls
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

SECURITY.YAML

```
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: DC=example,DC=com
                search_dn: "CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com"
                search_password: password
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: my_ldap
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LdapAuthenticator
            form_login_ldap:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'uid={user_identifier},dc=example,dc=com'
            entry_point: form_login_ldap
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Log file

```
[2022-12-08T15:01:57.363017+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\LdapController::login"},"request_uri":"https://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"POST"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:57.373679+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":2} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:57.373737+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:57.375104+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:57.993780+01:00] security.INFO: Authenticator failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid 1. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\LdapFinal\\vendor\\symfony\\security-http\\EventListener\\CheckCredentialsListener.php:69)","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.002159+01:00] security.DEBUG: The "App\Security\LdapAuthenticator" authenticator set the failure response. {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.010708+01:00] security.DEBUG: The "App\Security\LdapAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.101859+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\LdapController::login"},"request_uri":"https://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"GET"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.108085+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":2} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.108178+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.108209+01:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.108232+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.108260+01:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator"} []
[2022-12-08T15:01:58.248350+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"1fdb80"},"request_uri":"https://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/1fdb80","method":"GET"} []
```

i want Authenticat against an LDAP server in my symfony 6 app
this is my project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsxJdI7ESwfY21AMA3CgwV1bEroHmCON/view?usp=sharing
this is the ldap online server : https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/

Comment: In your config, Try to enclose the base_dn and password with double quotes.

Comment: no changes , same problem